# Facebook sharer.php showing empty shared url in mobile

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

Here http://strutmymutt.com/instagram/166924031442951647-4757182, when we click on facebook share button in mobile or iphone. It is showing empty url but it is working fine on the pcs.
I am using the facebook sharer.php for sharing the urls.

Comment: corrected issue is in the code

Comment: we have the same issue, could you please elaborate on what you fixed in the code to make this work?